# LINQ with String.Join() error: "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type '<DistinctIterator>

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to grab the distinct values of one column from a datatable using linq and use string.join to create a single string from the results but am getting:

"System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'd__7a`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'."

My code is:

```
Dim retString As String = ""

Dim uniqueCC2 = (From d As DataRow In dt.AsEnumerable() _
                 Select d.Field(Of String)("CageCardID")).Distinct

Try
     'I get the error on the following line
     retString = String.Join("</li><li>", uniqueCC2)
Catch ex As Exception
    ...error code...
End Try

Return "<li>" & retString & "</li>"
```

I have also tried this LINQ statement, but get the same error:

```
Dim uniqueCC2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(s As DataRow) s.Field(Of String)("CageCardID")).Distinct()
```

The column in question (CageCardID) is varchar(8)...so a string.

When I dive into uniqueCC2 it shows the values as strings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

George

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? 3.5 (Visual Studio 2008), by any chance? Try adding `.ToArray()` to the end of your query.

Comment: One side-note: i assume that you want to wrap the strings in `<li><\li>`. Then select them already so and you don't need the `String.Join`: `...Select String.Format("<li>{0}<\li>", d.Field(Of String)("CageCardID"))).Distinct()`

Comment: Thanks Anthony and Tim...great suggestions. It is working now. And yes, it is v3.5. George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using .NET <= 3.5 the overload which takes an [`IEnumerable(Of T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) is not available. You have to create an array first and use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
 retString = String.Join("</li><li>", uniqueCC2.ToArray())
```

Side-Note: if you want to wrap the strings in `<li>str</li>` you should not use `String.Join` but modify the `Select` in this way:

```
...
Select String.Format("<li>{0}</li>", d.Field(Of String)("CageCardID"))).Distinct()
```

Then the final string would be created in this way

```
Return String.Concat( uniqueCC2 ) ' no further delimiter needed
```

Comment: Though I don't think we are talking about mass data, I guess the  `string.Join` approach is more efficient (in time) than calling `string.Format()` for every single value.

Comment: Rene...yeah, it's usually around 20-100 items...so not big at all. Thanks!